# How to animate layout_constraintEnd attribute with intermediate states using MotionLayout?

Tags: android, animation, android-motionlayout

In my animation one of the views must grow from fixed `width` to `app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"` (which is the value from the destination `ConstraintSet`) by 70% of animation time.

I tried to achive it with the following `KeyAttribute`:

```
<KeyAttribute
    motion:motionTarget="@id/my_view"
    motion:framePosition="70"
    >
    <CustomAttribute
        motion:attributeName="layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf"
        motion:customReference="@id/root"/>
</KeyAttribute>
```

But it has no effect

**I would be grateful for working solution of this problem.**

Answer (score 0):

If in any case you are interested in Motion Layout for Constraint layout, then you can refer to this provided link for your animation [Motion Layout with Stevdza](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ROkKPgXpd1Y).

Comment: Looks like advertising of youtube channel rather than answer on my question

Answer (score 0):

MotionLayout animates Views between two ConstraintSets.
It cannot animate Constraints.

You define KeyPosition
With its Size reaching 100% of the size by frame 70.

- **Constraints** control the start and end.
- **KeyPosition** controls the evolution position & size from "start" to "end"
- **Attributes** typically control the viewTransform

For a brief introduction see the [KeyPosition video in the MotionTags Series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3HQMCyAkWTE)

This is roughly what it should look like:

```
    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@id/start"
        motion:duration="1000">
       <KeyFrameSet>
          <KeyPosition 
               motion:framePosition="70" 
               motion:motionTarget="@+id/view" 
               motion:sizePercent="1"/>
       </KeyFrameSet>
    </Transition>
    <ConstraintSet  android:id="@+id/end"
        motion:deriveConstraintsFrom="@id/start" >
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            />
    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
 <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            />
 </ConstraintSet>
```

Comment: Thanks for response. I tried it also. It is not working as expected: View really gets 100% size by 70% of time. The problem is it igrows both to the right and to the left. So left side of the view goes out of the screen, while right side keeps moving right. This is the reason I tried to use KeyAttribute instead of KeyPosition

Comment: You can accelerate the change in position by adding motion:percentX="1"

Comment: @hofold this wouldn't work either. percentX would move whole view to the right

Comment: I would have to actually see the motion you are trying to achieve know how to achieve it.